# dimension of a projective variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $Y$ be a projective variety with homogeneous coordinate ring $S(Y)$, where $S=k[x_{0},x_{1},\dots ,x_{n}]$ and $k$ is algebraically closed. Show that $\dim S(Y)=\dim Y+1$.

My solution so far:

Let $H_{i}=Z_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}(x_{i})$. Let $U_{i}=\mathbb{P}^{n}\setminus H_{i}$. $\phi:U_{i}\rightarrow A=k[y_{1},\dots ,y_{n}]$ is a homeopmorphism. Define $Y_{i}=\phi(Y\cap U_{i})$.

The plan is to show that $A(Y_{j})\cong (S(Y)_{x_{j}})_{0}$ (homogeneous elements of degree $0$ in the localization of $S$) for some $j$. The rest of the solution follows from there. I know that there exists $j$ such that $\dim Y=\dim A(Y_{j})$. I will assume that this $j=0$ for easy notation. $S$ is a graded ring with gradation $S=\oplus_{d\geq 0}S_{d}$ where $S_{d}$ consists of monomials of total degree $d$. Therefore
$$\displaystyle S(Y)_{x_{0}}=\bigoplus_{d\in\mathbb{Z}}(S_{x_{0}})_{d}/((S_{x_{0}})_{d}\cap I(Y)_{x_{0}}).$$
Any homogeneous element of degree $0$ has the form $f=\displaystyle \overline{\tfrac{\prod_{i\geq 1}^{n}x_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}}{x_{0}^{m}}}$ where $\sum\alpha_{i}=m$. I will define the polynomial on top as $F$ so $f=\tfrac{\overline{F}}{x_{0}^{m}}$. I think the appropriate map would be $\alpha:(S(Y)_{x_{0}})_{0}\rightarrow A(Y_{j})$ $f\mapsto F(1,\tfrac{x_{1}}{x_{0}},\dots ,\tfrac{x_{n}}{x_{0}})$. My problem is I don't know if this map is well defined (i.e.) if $f=\tfrac{\overline{F}}{x_{0}^{m}}$ and $f= \tfrac{\overline{G}}{x_{0}^{m}}$ is $F(1,\tfrac{x_{1}}{x_{0}},\dots ,\tfrac{x_{n}}{x_{0}})=G(1,\tfrac{x_{1}}{x_{0}},\dots ,\tfrac{x_{n}}{x_{0}})$. Also I don't really know what elements of $A(Y_{j})$ look like to verify this.

A hint would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me write what you wrote, just in my own notation.

Define $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to (S(Y)_{x_0})_0$ by

$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto \frac{\displaystyle x_0^m f\left(\frac{x_1}{x_0},\ldots,\frac{x_n}{x_0}\right)}{x_0^m}$$

where $m$ is the multidegree of $f$. This is clearly a well-defined $k$-algebra map. Moreover, it's easy to see that $f$ maps to $0$ if and only if $g(X_0,\ldots,X_n)=0$ for all $[X_0:\ldots:X_n]\in U_0$, where $\displaystyle g(x_0,\ldots,x_n)=x_0^m f\left(\frac{x_1}{x_0},\ldots,\frac{x_n}{x_0}\right)$. In other words, the kernel of this map is precisely $I(Y_0)$. Thus, we get an embedding $A(Y_0)\hookrightarrow (S(Y)_{x_0})_0$. This map is clearly surjective since it hits all of the generators.

So, $A(Y_0)\cong (S(Y_0)_{x_0})_0$, and so it's not hard to see that $A(Y_0)[x_0,x_0^{-1}]\cong S(Y)_{x_0}$. Taking fraction fields shows that

$$K(Y_0)(x_0)\cong \text{Frac}(S(Y))$$

as $k$-algebras. So,

$$\dim S(Y)=\text{tr.deg}_k \text{Frac}(S(Y))=\text{tr.deg}K(Y_0)(x_0)=\text{tr.deg}K(Y_0)+1=\dim Y+1$$

Of course, in the above, I took $i=0$, but it's the same (just notationally more annoying) for $i=1,2,\dots,n$.

Comment: Should the $n$ in the map be something else?

Comment: @TheNumber23 Whoops, typo. $n$ is the multidegree of $f$.

Comment: @TheNumber23 I just realized why $n$ was a bad choice :) Changed to $m$

Comment: @TheNumber23 Any reason for not upvoting? I only ask because people usually accept without upvoting when it's a grudging accept--is there anything I can do to improve my answer?

Comment: No I just don't understand the protocol I guess. Took me a bit to reason but that would have happened with a clear answer as well.

Comment: @TheNumber23 It's no problem :) I was just more concerned with whether or not I wrote something clear.

Comment: Well maybe while you are here. With this argument with the kernal, you are saying if $f\mapsto 0$ then $g\in I(Y)_{x_{0}}$ correct? Since the map is to the localization of the quotient?

Comment: @TheNumber23 I'm saying that if $f\mapsto 0$, $f^h$ (this is the homogenization of $f$) must vanish on some subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$. See that the set $f^h$ vanishes on actually forces $f$ to vanish on $Y_0$, so that it's in $I(Y_0)$

Comment: What is $K(Y_0)(x_0)$?

Comment: It is hard for me to see why $A(Y_0)[x_0,x_0^{-1}]\cong S(Y)_{x_0}$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JDZ  every element of $S(Y)_{x_0}$ can be written as $x_0^ah$ for some integer $a$ and a degree $0$ element $h$. So, the homomorphism (between graded rings) $A(Y_0)[x_0, x_0^{-1}]\to S(Y)_{x_0}$ is surjective. It is injective by looking at the gradation on both sides.